# Como fazer com que a movimentação de um paragrafo não influencie em outros elementos

Tags: css, html5, posicionamento

Toda vez que a div .content se movimenta, o texto se auto ajusta ao tamanho dela, mas, faz com que a imagem/div dentro também se mexa, quero manter a imagem fixa na div sem sofrer influência dos outros elementos.

segue código:

http://jsfiddle.net/turiba/tpz1gka3/8/

Comment: Você se refere ao ajuste do texto em relação ao espaço da div? Se for, basta colocar o texto do 'contentParagraph' dentro de uma tag e definir a largura máxima

Comment: Não, me refiro ao ajuste da imagem, que está na primeira div .content. Ela só aparece se passar o mouse. Queria que ela ficasse fixa dentro da div, se sofrer interferencia do texto.

Comment: Seu HTML tá mal formado, tem coisa sobrando e tem coisa faltando. E se consertar seu layout para de funcionar o_O . . . . Tem certeza que precisa de tanto CSS? Isso atrapalha o diagnóstico.

Comment: Cara, eu dei uma enxugada no meu css e fiz alguns poucos ajustes no html. Caso você não tenha entendido o meu problema, ele está nas divs da classe .content, queria fazer um paragrafo sobrepor a imagem.

Comment: Talvez seja o caso de deixar a imagem com a posição absoluta?

Comment: Ja coloquei em absolute mas a imagem se movimenta juntamente à div.

Comment: Porque não coloca o texto em uma div de tamanho fixo e depois uma div com a imagem dentro da div content http://jsfiddle.net/tpz1gka3/15/

Answer (score 1):

Eu não entendi muito bem o propósito, mas para fazer isso sem muita gambiarra, você poderia usar a imagem como background.

http://jsfiddle.net/tpz1gka3/14/